# How to override style of Library components while using CSS Modules?

Tags: next.js, react-css-modules

I'm using NextJS, which use CSS Module, I want to use some CSS Library likes Material UI, ... But how to override style of components that I import from those Library?..

Answer (score 4):

After read documents from https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules .Seriously, it's quite simple, just use :global scope.
Ex:

```
.className :global(.lib-component-classname){
  // Style here apply to component that's imported from libs
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can always use the [`!important`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_important.asp) suffix after your style rule, but thats not really recommended because it goes against the Cascading of your Style Sheets (CSS).

What worked for me is using the `:global` selector, like DucHT explained, like this:

```css
:global(li.ant-menu-item).siderMenuItem {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 26px;
  padding-bottom: 26px;
}
```

Comment: Any other new ways to override the css? i tried your solution its not working my case @wilbo

Answer (score 4):

Building on @DucHT's answer, for people like me who really prefer it spelled out totally:

// MyComponent.tsx:

```
import LibraryComponent from 'some-library'
import styles from './MyComponent.module.scss'

export default function MyComponent({}) {
  return (
    <div>
      <LibraryComponent className={styles.classNameICanChoose} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

// MyComponent.module.scss:

```
.classNameICanChoose :global(.lib-component-classname){
  // Style here apply to component that's imported from libs
  // will overwrite .lib-component-classname
}
```